# Mockito and PowerMock MethodNotFoundException being thrown

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, powermock

Running into the below error when using Powermockito and Mockito to build some simple unit tests for a connection pool I made that wraps around Hikari CP.  The setup of the tests are below.  What is confusing to me is I have a whole handful of unit tests that are not shown and they all pass using the same setup and methods.  Just this one unit test continues to fail with that error.  And it doesn't matter what `when` statement I put at the top, they all can't find the method.

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: No methods matching the name(s) getColumnCount were found in the class hierarchy of class java.lang.Object.

at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getMethods(WhiteboxImpl.java:1720)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getMethods(WhiteboxImpl.java:1745)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getBestMethodCandidate(WhiteboxImpl.java:983)
at org.powermock.core.MockGateway$MockInvocation.findMethodToInvoke(MockGateway.java:317)
at org.powermock.core.MockGateway$MockInvocation.init(MockGateway.java:356)
at org.powermock.core.MockGateway$MockInvocation.<init>(MockGateway.java:307)
at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:142)
at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.methodCall(MockGateway.java:125)
at com.datafiniti.utils.mysqlconnpool.MysqlConnPoolTests.executeStringQuery(MysqlConnPoolTests.java:149)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:316)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:300)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:288)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:208)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:121)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:123)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Here is the unit tests:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MysqlConnPoolTests {

private HikariConfig mockHikariConfig;
private HikariDataSource hikariDataSource;

@Before
@PrepareForTest({HikariConfig.class, HikariDataSource.class})
public void beforEachTest() throws Exception {

    // mock the hikari confic used within the connection pool
    mockHikariConfig = PowerMockito.mock(HikariConfig.class);

    // mock hikari config constructor
    PowerMockito.whenNew(HikariConfig.class)
            .withNoArguments()
            .thenReturn(mockHikariConfig);

    // mock hikari config data source setting
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(mockHikariConfig)
            .setDataSourceClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource");

    // mock the hikari data source used within the connection pool
    hikariDataSource = PowerMockito.mock(HikariDataSource.class);

    // mock hikari data source constructor
    PowerMockito.whenNew(HikariDataSource.class)
            .withParameterTypes(HikariConfig.class)
            .withArguments(Mockito.isA(HikariConfig.class))
            .thenReturn(hikariDataSource);
}

@Test
@PrepareForTest({MysqlConnectionPool.class, Connection.class, Statement.class, ResultSet.class, ResultSetMetaData.class})
public void executeStringQuery() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.spy(MysqlConnectionPool.class);

    Connection mockConnection = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
    Statement mockStatement = Mockito.mock(Statement.class);
    ResultSet mockResultSet = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
    ResultSetMetaData mockMeta = Mockito.mock(ResultSetMetaData.class);

    Mockito.when(mockMeta.getColumnCount()).thenReturn(1);
    Mockito.when(mockMeta.getColumnLabel(1)).thenReturn("foo");

    Mockito.when(mockResultSet.first()).thenReturn(true);
    Mockito.when(mockResultSet.next()).thenReturn(false);
    Mockito.when(mockResultSet.getString(1)).thenReturn("bar");

    Mockito.when(mockStatement.execute(Mockito.eq("SELECT * FROM table;"))).thenReturn(true);
    Mockito.when(mockStatement.getResultSet()).thenReturn(mockResultSet);

    Mockito.when(mockConnection.createStatement()).thenReturn(mockStatement);

    Mockito.when(hikariDataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(mockConnection);

    MysqlConnectionPool pool = new MysqlConnectionPool().create();
    List<Map<String, String>> result = pool.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table;");

    assertEquals(1, result.size());
    assertTrue(result.get(0).containsKey("foo"));
    assertEquals("bar", result.get(0).get("foo"));
}
```

}

Comment: Try put @PrepareForTest  with all your class before 'public class MysqlConnPoolTests' and remove it before tests. I sometimes see strange behavior when PrepareForTest  when it is declared on test level.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Going to post an answer just in case someone else sees this.   Reverting all versions to 1.6.5 solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so unfortunately I am using the answer space to comment.

Markll, I am running into similar issues, here's my SO question - [org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: - when mocking java sql classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40964605/org-powermock-reflect-exceptions-methodnotfoundexception-when-mocking-java-sq)
Does Mockito.when(mockConnection.createStatement()).thenReturn(mockStatement); work for you? Mine doesn't even get past that. May be you can help me with that. My latest conclusion is since Connection, Statement and ResultSets are actually interfaces not classes, that's the reason it's throwing the error saying it can't find in the hierarchy of Object.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, definitely seems like a bug.  I did some debugging through mine and realized its changing the class it is searching for the method for from the one given to java.lang.Object.  Of course the method I'm asking for is not in there.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a bug. I would suggest may be you should write it up in the issues section of PowerMock github repo with what you observed in debugging. I haven't gone down the debugging rabbit hole yet or I would have done it myself.

Comment: Seems like there is already a bug filed - https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/717.

Comment: I changed my powermock dependency to 1.6.5 and it worked. You can try checking with that.

Comment: That worked!  So it's definitely a bug in their latest version.

Comment: @user2237511, a month later and you've helped me out too :) Thanks a lot.